# mediaPlayer crash when using mediaPlayer.release()

Tags: kotlin, media-player

we have RecyclerView with list of children songs, when you click on a song it takes you to another activity mediaPlayer.. The problem is that when I play a song and then use back bottom the song stop and that is ok, and application stop this is the problem, but when I comment //mediaPlayer.release() the application works well it didn't crash and the song only stop when I go back, but the problem is that when I choose another song from RecyclerView and click PlayBotton the song starts from the start but the SeekBar seeks to the end and don't move. does any body have idea how to solve this?

I tried to but mediaPlayer.release() between Try and Catch but the problem still the same.

```
class ChildrenSongsPreview : AppCompatActivity() {

private var handler = Handler()
var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = null
private var startTime = 0.0
private var finalTime = 0.0

private var updateSongTime = object : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        startTime = mediaPlayer?.currentPosition!!.toDouble()
        txt_playing_duration.text = String.format(
            "%d:%d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(startTime.toLong()),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(startTime.toLong()) -
                    TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(startTime.toLong())
                    )
        )

        songs_seekbar.progress = startTime.toInt()
        handler.postDelayed(this, 100)
    }
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_children_songs_preview)

    var pos = intent.getIntExtra("KEY_SONG", 0)
    var song_ID: Int = R.raw.zahab_elel

    when (pos) {
        0 -> {
            song_ID = R.raw.mama_zmanha_gaya
            txt_song_name_preview.text = "ماما زمانها جاية"
        }
        1 -> {
            song_ID = R.raw.zahab_elel
            txt_song_name_preview.text = "ذهب الليل"
        }
        2 -> {
            song_ID = R.raw.gdo_ali
            txt_song_name_preview.text = "جدو علي"
        }
        3 -> {
            song_ID = R.raw.ebre2_shay
            txt_song_name_preview.text = "إبريق الشاي"
        }
    }

    var position = 0
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, song_ID)

    //set song duration
    finalTime = mediaPlayer?.duration!!.toDouble()
    txt_song_duration.text = String.format(
        "%d:%d",
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(finalTime.toLong()),
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(finalTime.toLong()) -
                TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(finalTime.toLong()))
    )

    btn_play.setOnClickListener {
        mediaPlayer?.seekTo(position)
        mediaPlayer?.start()
        btn_play.visibility = View.GONE
        btn_pause.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        if (oneTimeOnly == 0) {
            songs_seekbar!!.max = finalTime.toInt()
            oneTimeOnly = 1
        }

        songs_seekbar!!.progress = startTime.toInt()
        handler.postDelayed(updateSongTime, 100)
    }

    btn_pause.setOnClickListener {
        position = mediaPlayer?.currentPosition!!
        mediaPlayer?.pause()
        btn_pause.visibility = View.GONE
        btn_play.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

    btn_stop.setOnClickListener {
        mediaPlayer?.stop()
        position = 0
        btn_pause.visibility = View.GONE
        btn_play.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, song_ID)
    }

    mediaPlayer?.setOnCompletionListener {
        position = 0
        btn_pause.visibility = View.GONE
        btn_play.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, song_ID)
    }

    songs_seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
        override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, p: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
            if (fromUser) {
                position = p
            }
        }

        override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
        }

        override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
            mediaPlayer?.seekTo(position)
        }
    })
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    mediaPlayer?.stop()
    mediaPlayer?.release()
}

companion object {
    var oneTimeOnly = 0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Media player instance should also be released in `onDestroy()`

```
override fun onDestroy() {
        mediaPlayer?.release()
        mediaPlayer = null
        super.onDestroy()
    }
```

Comment: when I do this the application crash when I go back to RecyclerView activity

Comment: Try making it null! This is a hack just let me know what happens!

Comment: I tried It and the application still crash.. but I solved it by using `override fun onDestroy() {
        mediaPlayer?.stop()
        super.onDestroy()
    }` and I deleted this line `oneTimeOnly = 1` so the seekBar starts from begaining.. Thanks Sharan for your help.

Comment: Can you give it as an accepted answer will give me points for putting up time and efforts? Thanks :)